# Can i use VS2010 PrivateObject to access a static field inside a static class?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to get access to a private static field inside a static class, using the VS2010 Unit Test class PrivateObject ?

Let say i have the following class:

```
public static class foo
{
    private static bar;
}
```

Can i use PrivateObject to create a copy of ***foo***, and then get the ***bar*** field?

Comment: Why do you need to access a private field in a unit test? It is generally not a best practice to do so.

Comment: I cannot change the tested code, however i do want to get data from a specific private field....

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Get Private Field from Static Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628666/c-get-private-field-from-static-class)

Comment: I get the impression this isn't for a unit test... voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Actually this is for a Unit Test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The property value can be retreived using reflection. This will require the use of [Type.GetField Method (String, BindingFlags)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e.aspx) and the [FieldInfo.GetValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx)

```
string propertyName = "bar";
FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(foo).GetField(propertyName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
object fieldValue = fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
```

Answer (score 32):

PrivateType class is analogous to PrivateObject for invoking private static members. Overloaded GetStaticFieldOrProperty methods may be used.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privatetype(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: InvokeStatic method should be used.

Answer (score 10):

The answer by Deepun can be very useful.  I wanted to add a specific example to help people who come this way.

Class with private static member.

```
public class foo
{
   private static int bar;
}
```

Code to get value.

```
PrivateType pt = new PrivateType(typeof(foo));
int bar = (int)pt.GetStaticFieldOrProperty("bar");
```

Code to change value

```
PrivateType pt = new PrivateType(typeof(foo));
pt.SetStaticFieldOrProperty("bar", 10);
```

This will work regardless of the class being static or not.