# Creating a list of static objects in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, appdomain

Is it possible to retrieve all the static objects which have been created in the current appdomain?  I'm trying to write a debug page for an existing asp.net web site. which holds a lot of information in a caches based on singleton objects.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

```
IList<Assembly> assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

List<Type> allTypes = new List<Type>();

foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
{
    var types = from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                where bootStrapperType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                    && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract
                select t;

    allTypes.AddRange(types);
}

foreach(Type type in allTypes)
{
    var fieldsPublic = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach(var field in fieldsPublic)
    {
       var nameAndValue = field.Name + " = " + field.GetValue(null);
       // Do something
    }
    var fieldsPrivate = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Private|BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach(var field in fieldsPrivate)
    {
       var nameAndValue = field.Name + " = " + field.GetValue(null);
       // Do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - that has pointed me in the correct direction.  In order to remove constants from the results I also need to check for field.IsLiteral

Answer (score -1):

I've come across [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628666/c-sharp-get-private-field-from-static-class) sometime ago. You need to know the types that contain those static fields though. But you can iterate over all loaded assembles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currently-loaded-assemblies) and check every type.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question (it doesn't, by the way), [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.